# virtualenv not setting virtual environment

Tags: python, linux, debian, virtualenv

in debian based Linux i am trying to uninstall a package installed by pip but for removing it after search it says it will only uninstall it in virtual environment after install virtualenv and upgrading it to version 15.0.3 i run command

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages /usr
```

then error occured that it is being run by interpreter and please use *system* python to execute the script

then i changed the python version via -p flag to python3 then it says the same msg that already using the python3 interpreter i also used simple python version still no luck

i trolled the stackoverflow & google but got no valid answer

Answer (score 0):

Finally after searching and experimenting a lot I just owerwrited the new version of twisted by downloading the old one some of the files it did not deleted however all packages in the system started using newly downloaded old version of twisted!